# How to replace all newlines after reading a file

Tags: javascript

How can I replace a newline in a string with a `','`? I have a string that is read from a file:

```
const fileText = (<FileReader>fileLoadedEvent.target).result.toString();
file.readCSV(fileText);
```

It takes a string from a file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
,,,,,
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

I'm able to detect the newline with this:

```
if (char === '\n')
```

But replacing \n like this doesn't work

```
str = csvString.replace('/\n/g');
```

I want to get the string to look like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,
,,,,,,
g,h,i,j,k,l,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `,` at end of each line like this

- `$` - Matches end of line

```js
let str = `a,b,c,d,e,f
,,,,,
g,h,i,j,k,l`

let op = str.replace(/$/mg, "$&"+ ',')

console.log(op)
```

Comment: what is the second arg of replace for? "$&"+

Comment: @mattiscodings it is reference to whole mathc [Read here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacematch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the pattern `$` with `,`, comma:

```js
var input = 'a,b,c,d,e,f';
input = input.replace(/$/mg, ",");
console.log(input);
```

Since you intend to retain the newlines/carriage returns, we can just take advantage of `$` to represent the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in some systems newline is `\r\n` or just `\r`, so give `/\r?\n|\r/` a shot

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = `a,b,c,d,e,f
,,,,,
g,h,i,j,k,l`;

let edited = text.replace(/\s+/g, '');

console.log( edited )
```

You can try this solution also. `\s` means white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may try out like,

```js
// Let us have some sentences havin linebreaks as \n.

let statements = " Programming is so cool. \n We love to code. \n We can built what we want. \n :)";

// We will console it and see that they are working fine.
console.log(statements);

// We may replace the string via various methods which are as follows,

// FIRST IS USING SPLIT AND JOIN
let statementsWithComma1 = statements.split("\n").join(",");

// RESULT
console.log("RESULT1 : ", statementsWithComma1);

// SECOND IS USING REGEX
let statementsWithComma2 = statements.replace(/\n/gi, ',');

// RESULT
console.log("RESULT2 : ", statementsWithComma2);

// THIRS IS USING FOR LOOP
let statementsWithComma3 = "";

for(let i=0; i < statements.length; i++){
  if(statements[i] === "\n")
    statementsWithComma3 += ','
  else
    statementsWithComma3 += statements[i]
}

// RESULT
console.log("RESULT3 : ", statementsWithComma3);
```